# pattern to get video id from youtube URL

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I have tried following pattern to get youtube id from a youtube URL. It seems working for normal youtube URL,

```
$pattern = 
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /&v=/       # or ?feature=youtu.be&v=NXwxHU2Q0bo
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        $%x'
        ;
        $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
        if ($result) {
            return $matches[1];
        }
```

But fails for this URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=NXwxHU2Q0bo
and 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=w7P_F7DGPU0

What is the pattern need to include to get the video ID from above URL? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I might be wrong but why don't you use a library that just parse an url and give you a dictionary of key-values for each parameter. And then just get the value of the "v" key ?

Comment: Have you tried this pattern? $pattern = '/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;'

Comment: `parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $vars );`  Your video id is then at `$vars['v']`.

Comment: Thank you for this question :) I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
^# Match any youtube URL
    (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
    (?:
        www\. # Optional www subdomain
      | m\.   # Optional mobile subdomain
    )?      
    (?:             # Group host alternatives
      youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
      (?:           # Group path alternatives
        /           # Shortlink
      | /embed/     # Either /embed/
      | /v/         # or /v/
      | /&v=/       # or ?feature=youtu.be&v=NXwxHU2Q0bo
      | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
      | /watch\?feature=youtu\.be&v= # alternativ link with watch
      )             # End path alternatives.
    )               # End host alternatives.
    ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
    $
```

https://regex101.com/r/LiCquP/2

https://regex101.com/r/LiCquP/3

For the test :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` functions. Here's an example iterating through the two URLs you provided:

```
<?php
$youtube_urls = array(
    'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=w7P_F7DGPU0',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=NXwxHU2Q0bo'
);

foreach($youtube_urls as $youtube_url){
    $video_id = NULL;

    $parsed_url = parse_url($youtube_url);

    if( isset($parsed_url['query']) ){
        parse_str($parsed_url['query'],$query_params);

        if( isset($query_params['v']) ){
            $video_id = $query_params['v'];
        }

    }

    echo $video_id.'<br>';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Also, you could use the `PHP_URL_QUERY` component as the second parameter of `parse_url()` which would spit out the query string directly.